# Reading objects from a file in c++

Tags: c++, serialization, file-io

I am trying to read objects I had earlier written(there is only one object in the file right now) in the file 'CustomerDetails'. My program always terminates abruptly after `read first object` is couted.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
ifstream file;
try
{
  file.open("CustomerDetails.dat",fstream::in|fstream::binary);
  if(file.is_open())
  {
    while(1)
    {
      cout<<"Current Position\n"<<file.tellg()<<endl;
      file.read((char*)this,sizeof(*this));
      if(file.eof()) break;

      cout<<"read first object\n";
      if(!(this->accountNo).compare(accountNumber)&& this->isDeleted==false)
      {
          cout<<"Account Found!!\n Current Balance="<<this->balanceAmount<<endl;
      }              
      cout<<"End of loop loop\n";            
    }
  }
  else
  {
      cout<<"Error opening file.\n";
  }
  file.close();
}
catch(...)
{
  cout<<"Exception Caught\n";
}
```

Comment: First of all, make the read call in the loop condition, like `while (file.read(...)) { ... }`. Second of all, you read into `this` over and over again, when you should use a separate function for the deserialization which creates all objects from the file. Thirdly, you can't use this method if you have anything but trivial data members, it won't work if you have e.g. `std::vector`, `std::string`, pointers, and other non-trivial data. Fourthly, use an existing framework for serialization like [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this helps..my class did include a few `string` variables. any idea on how to write `const string variable` to a class..i am overloading the insertion operator to write strings to a file.

Comment: It's not trivial, which is why I recommend you use an existing serialization library. Otherwise you have to write and read all members one by one, and for variable-length values (like a `std::string`) you also have to write/read the length as well.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the idea you have here only work in very specific cases when the data is always sequentially in memory in a single block. This is simple not true for any even slightly complex situation (specifically if there is a string it's never going to work).

The assignment seems to imply you should override the >> operator to the output streams and then write every element of the class to the stream independently noting lengths or using break characters to indicate where variable length data ends. As suggested in the comments this is not a trivial task.

Similarly the deserialization code must reverse this process from the stream.